# How to find the "exit" of a C program

Tags: c, linux, assembly, binary

The test is on `32-bit x86` Linux.

So basically I am trying to log the information of **executed basic blocks** by insert instrumentation instructions in assembly code.

My strategy is like this: Write the index of a executed basic block in a globl array, and flush the array from memory to the disk when the array is full (16M).

Here is my problem. I need the flush the array to the disk when the execution of instrumented binary is over, even if it does not reach 16M boundary. However, I just don't know where to find the exit of a `assembly` program.

I tried this:

1. `grep exit` from the target assembly program, and flush the memory right before the `call exit` instruction. But according to some debugging experience, the target C program, say, a `md5sum` binary, does not call `exit` when it finishes the execution.
2. Flush the memory at the end of `main` function. However, in the assembly code, I just don't know where is the exact end of `main` function. I can do a conservative approach, say, looking for all the `ret` instruction, but it seems to me that not all the `main` function ends with a `ret` instruction.

So here is my question, how to identify the exact execution end of a `assembly code` , and insert some instrumentation instructions there? Hooking some library code is fine to me. I understand with different input, binary could exit at different position, so I guess I need some conservative estimation. Am I clear? thanks!

Comment: Is your instrumentation some free software? I would be glad to look inside your code....

Comment: I don't think thats always well defined. Once a optimizer has done its job, there might not even be defined boundaries between functions, or even between `main()` and the stuff from libc that is called before it (the program's entrypoint). A possible clue would be to keep track of how stack is being used, but again, I don't think its necessarily true that the stack will be fully reversed when the program is exiting.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you cannot do that in the general case. First, if `main` is returning some code, it is an exit code (if `main` has no explicit `return` the recent C standards require that the compiler adds an *implicit* `return 0;`). Then a function could store the address of `exit` in some data (e.g. a global function, a field in a `struct`, ...), and some *other* function could *indrectly* call that thru a function pointer. Practically, a program can load some plugins using `dlopen` and use `dlsym` for `"exit"` name, or simply call `exit` inside the plugin, etc... AFAIU solving that problem (of finding actual `exit` calls, in the dynamic sense) in full generality can be proved equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). See also [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Without claiming an exhaustive approach, I would suggest something else (assuming you are interested in instrumenting programs coded in C or C++, etc... whose source code is available to you). You could customize the GCC compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to change the basic blocks processed inside GCC to call some of your instrumentation functions. It is not trivial, but it is doable... Of course you'll need to recompile some C code with such a customized GCC to instrument it.

<sup>(Disclaimer, I am the main author of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); feel free to contact me for more...)</sup>

BTW, do you know about [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)? It could be helpful for your flushing issue... And you might also use `LD_PRELOAD` tricks (read about [dynamic linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), see [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)).

Answer (score 2):

[`atexit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) will properly handle 95+% of programs.  You can either modify its chain of registered handlers, or instrument it as you are other blocks.  However, some programs may terminate by use of [`_exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/_exit) which does not invoke *atexit* handlers.  Probably instrumenting *_exit* to invoke data flushing and installing an atexit (or [`on_exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/on_exit) on BSD-like programs) handler should cover nearly 100% of programs.

---

Addendum:  Note that the *Linux Base Specification* [says](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html) that the C library startup shall:

> call the initializer function (*init)().
>   call main() with appropriate arguments.
>   call exit() with the return value from main().

Comment: It depends if the program being debugged is written using a regular development tool chain or not: Most programs written in assembler (for learning purposes) call the "exit" system call directly which means that "on_exit" or "atexit" functions are not handled. When a program is interrupted by "kill" this is also the case.

Comment: @MartinRosenau:  How many non-student assembly programs might there be on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

A method that should be working everytime would be to create a shared memory section for storing your data there.

You also create a child process which is waiting for the process being debugged to finish.

As soon as the process being debugged has finished the child process will finalize the write operations using the data that is in the shared memory.

This should work on all forms of exit, process interruptions (e.g. Ctrl+C, closing the terminal window, ...) or even if the process has been killed using "kill".

Answer (score 0):

> But according to some debugging experience, the target C program, say, a md5sum binary, does not call exit when it finishes the execution.

Let's take a look at a `md5sum` binary on an `i686` GNU/Linux system:

In the disassembly (`objdump -d /usr/bin/md5sum`) we have this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08048f50 <.text>:
 8048f50:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048f51:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048f53:       57                      push   %edi
 8048f54:       56                      push   %esi
 8048f55:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048f56:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048f59:       81 ec c0 00 00 00       sub    $0xc0,%esp
 8048f5f:       8b 7d 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%edi

[ ... ]

 8049e8f:       68 b0 d6 04 08          push   $0x804d6b0
 8049e94:       68 40 d6 04 08          push   $0x804d640
 8049e99:       51                      push   %ecx
 8049e9a:       56                      push   %esi
 8049e9b:       68 50 8f 04 08          push   $0x8048f50
 8049ea0:       e8 4b ef ff ff          call   8048df0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 8049ea5:       f4                      hlt
```

This is all startup boilerplate code. The actual program's `main` call is invoked inside the call [`__libc_start_main`](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html).  If the program returns from that, then, hey look, there is a `hlt` instruction. That's your target. Look for that `hlt` instruction and instrument that as the end of the program.

Comment: Technically `__libc_start_main()` should never return. The `hlt` should never be reached. `__libc_start_main` will at one point invoke one of the exit functions which will do a `sys_exit` system call to terminate the user program.

Comment: Interestingly, `hlt` is a privileged instruction and will actually raise an exception. See the discussion in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29502615/2866527) and [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/13/how-statically-linked-programs-run-on-linux). LSB Specification for `__libc_start_main()` is [here](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html).

Comment: @Edward That sort of makes sense; under virtualization, it's very useful for the VM monitor to know when the guest OS is idle.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
int main() 
bool keepGoing = true;
{
    while(keepGoing) {
        string x;
        cin >> x;
        if(x == "stop") {
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

even though it is primitive... I probably butchered the coding but it's just a concept.

Comment: This is wrong (you are declaring a variable, `keepGoing`, between `main()` and the brace!) and it requires user interaction (`cin`) to work. I don't think you have understood the question.